# Is there a simple way to check if an incoming caller is a contact in Android?

Tags: android, contacts, telephony

When an Android phone receives a call it automatically checks if the call exists in its own contact database. I was wondering if there is a simple way to access that information. I have a `PhoneStateListener` that performs certain actions during a ringing state, and I want to check if the incoming caller is in the contacts list.

Is there a way to do this without going through the Contacts `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Can I ask why you dont want to do it through the content provider?

Listening out for an incoming call, retrieving the number and then checking if its in the content provider seems to be the logical way to do it?

Comment: You're right, it would be a decent way to go, however I want to avoid it because of complications regarding the phone "type". Since a user can put a contact's phone number into any category (e.g. "Work", "Other" or even a custom one) it becomes ugly trying to search through all of the fields to find a match. Besides, there is also a need to format the numbers in a standard way. Am I missing something very simple? If not, I'd rather stay away from that mess altogether.

Comment: The code from Christopher below should work fine, I use something similiar to check an outgoing number and it checks all fields without any delay in the processing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phone app uses the contacts `ContentProvider` too; I'm not sure why you would want to avoid that.  Besides, it's the only publicly-accessible way of accessing that information.

Resolving a number to a name (pre 2.0, in this case) is simple enough anyway:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

String name = null;
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, 
                    new String[] { Phones.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Aha! I knew I was getting confused with the URIs somewhere! Thank you very much, this worked like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, that provider URI does all the number formatting and matching for you.. no need to worry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for 2.0 and later

```
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);        

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: instead of PhoneLookup cannot we just use Phone?