# How can I query contact information based on a phone number

Tags: android, android-1.6-donut

I am trying to query contact information based on a phone number on android 1.6. This is the code I tried. But I get count equals to 0 in my cursor.

```
    String selection = "PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL(" + People.Phones.NUMBER + " , "   + phoneNumber + ")";
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {People._ID, People.NAME, People.Phones.NUMBER},
            selection, null, null);
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a simple way to check if an incoming caller is a contact in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193664/is-there-a-simple-way-to-check-if-an-incoming-caller-is-a-contact-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a URI to and use a query to directly get a contact info by phone number..

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
```

The cursor returned by the code above should then contain the contact you are looking for and you can get the info out you need...

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    int personIDIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID);
    //etc
}
```

Comment: This is easily the least complicated way to query a contact. I've done a lot of research and have uncovered many ways to do this, but this is by far the easiest. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Phone numbers are stored in their own table and need to be queried separately. To query the phone number table use the URI stored in the SDK variable Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI. Use a WHERE conditional to get the phone numbers for the specified contact.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
        cur.getColumnIndex(People.PRIMARY_PHONE_ID))) > 0) {
    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
            Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, 
            Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID +" = ?", 
            new String[]{id}, null);
    int i=0;
    int pCount = pCur.getCount();
    String[] phoneNum = new String[pCount];
    String[] phoneType = new String[pCount];
    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
        phoneNum[i] = pCur.getString(
                           pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.NUMBER));
        phoneType[i] = pCur.getString(
                           pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.TYPE));
        i++;
    } 
}
```

Query the phones table and get a Cursor stored in pCur. Since the Android contacts database can store multiple phone numbers per contact we need to loop through the returned results. In addition to returning the phone number the query also returned the type of number (home, work, mobile, etc).

Also read this tutorial about [Working With Android Contacts API For 1.6 and Before](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/2/)